# Swap pairs of elements in a list using pattern matching

Tags: list, recursion, pattern-matching, sml

I need to use pattern matching techniques, in order to recursively swap every pair of elements in a list. So, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` would return `[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]`.

Two things I have found:

- `List.length`: to return the length. Which is helpful to deal with even/odd lists.
- `List.nth`: to return a value at the designated spot in the list.
- `drop.(list, i)`: to return the values after the first i elements are dropped.

Using those three things, I can sort of figure out some recursion methods, but I don't understand the pattern matching aspect. Below is some pseudocode without any pattern matching.

```
function(list):
  var a = first on list
  var b = second on list

  // odd case
  if(b = null | "")
  {
    list = drop.(list, 1) @ a
  }

  // even case
  else if(b = "" & a = "")
  {
    list = list
  }

  // recursive case
  else
  {
    list = function(drop.(list, 2) @ b @ a)
  }
```

This could essentially, start looping through the list, swapping the pairs, placing(concatenating) them at the end of the list, and recursively repeating this until it has gone through all pairs.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting homework problem. How do you intend to solve it? Perhaps you can share your efforts towards a solution and ask a more focused question.

Comment: If you are thinking about a for loop then you aren't thinking functionally and you aren't thinking in terms of pattern matching. Surely your textbook has examples of recursive functions on lists that are defined using pattern matching. Try to emulate such examples.

Comment: Start with a pattern-matching function - no `nth` or `take` or  `drop`, only patterns - that just returns the first two elements of a list. (Think about what to do when there are fewer than two; you're going to need more than one clause.) Then return them swapped. Then add recursion over the rest of the list.

Comment: You're not actually asking a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions `List.length`, `List.nth` and `List.drop` seem like they might solve your task, but this is counterproductive to your goal of using pattern matching. With pattern matching you're using that lists are algebraic data types declared sort of like

```
datatype 'a list = [] | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

which produces value constructors `[]` for empty list and the infix `::` operator for *cons*'ing an element in front of an existing list (that is either empty or created in the same way), but also *pattern constructors* for recognizing what kind of list you're dealing with.

*Example:* A function that takes a list of integers and sums them:

```
fun sum [] = 0
  | sum (x::xs) = x + sum xs
```

*Example:* A function that takes a list of 2-tuples and returns a similar list of 2-tuples but with the elements in each 2-tuple swapped:

```
fun swap [] = []
  | swap ((x,y)::xys) = (y,x)::swap xys
```

*Example:* A function that takes an even-sized list of integers and returns a list where they've been added together in pairs:

```
fun addpairs (x::y::xys) = x + y :: addpairs xys
  | addpairs [_x] = raise Fail "Odd-sized list"
  | addpairs [] = []
```

In particular, patterns can be nested (`(x,y)::xys` ~~ "the list with at least one element where the first element is a 2-tuple with the first part of it named `x` and the second part named `y`" and `x::y::xys` ~~ "the list with at least two elements in it with the first element named `x` and the second element named `y`"), and order (matching from top to bottom) might matter if patterns overlap (which they don't in any of the above).